# New to Java, Can someone please explain me how the output is 13 15 x ? for this code?

Tags: java

```
class Output {

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Output o = new Output();
        o.go();
    }

    void go() {
        int y = 7;
        for(int x = 1; x < 8; x++) {
            y++;
            if (x > 4) {
                System.out.print(++y + " ");
            }
            if (y > 14) {
                System.out.println(" x = " + x);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why would OP feel awful to receive some good advice?

Comment: I assume your question probably relates to `++y`, which just means increment y **before** printing the value. The rest of the problem should be traceable with pen and paper

Comment: Maybe OP has no debugger.

Comment: You incremented `y` a couple of times in the latter loop iterations.

Comment: "Maybe OP has no debugger." That's reaching, but if true is easily fixed so that they can debug their code, which they should do. They clearly have Internet access and a computer and some sort of Java development environment, so there's nothing to stop them from doing the right thing.

Comment: @nicomp Pen and paper works just as effectively when going line by line through the execution of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your doubts probably are related to the use of:

x++: which increments the value after use of current
++y: which first increments and then use the new value

Running it we have these variables states in paper
[Click here to see the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Gf9x.jpg)

Note when x=5 and x=6 , the ++y is executed when printed, and by this you see two increments for each iteration.

Hope this clarify your doubt.

Luigi.